# Auto adjust height (make equal height) of all elements using CSS / CSS3

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have an unordered list of navigation items that are displayed inline, each of these item share the same equal width of the container (ie. 320px).

The issue I'm facing is there is a potential that the text might runover two lines because of the limited width. But is it possible to make all navigation items hyperlink the same height should one be taller than the others?

The background color is applied to the hyperlink because it needs an active state when content is active.

Heres my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/calebo/W7sYZ/1/

Comment: Any particular reason not to apply the styling to the table-cell elements? i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/zKQVM/

Comment: There is an active/inactive state that needs to be applied to the hyperlinks. See updated fiddle.

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, wouldn't it be better if the navigation always stays a fixed height? i.e. adjust the width until no text takes more than one line. Or is the width a requirement?

Comment: I want the width of all the nav items to always expand full width of the container, thus using table-cell value on the items. Would not prefer a fix height which is not flexible, and if they text runs over 2lines, the layout would break.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){

    var heighest = 0;
    $('.tab-set li a').each(function(){
        heighest = ($(this).height() > heighest) ? $(this).height() : heighest;

    });

    $('.tab-set li a').css('height',heighest + 'px');

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W7sYZ/2/

Comment: I'm looking for a non-js solution preferably. As per my question tags. :)

Comment: This is not a CSS solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
.module-controls { display: table; }
.module-controls .tab-set { display: table-row; }
```

Multibrowser variant without JS: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Comment: This works, though it will widen the <li> to prevent the line-break. If the OP does not mind some <li>'s being wider than others, this gets my vote for a non-js solution.

Comment: Unfortunately the width of the container is fluid therefore I need the <li> elements to always expend to fit full screen.

Comment: And where is the contradiction? Set .module-controls width.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple:

Put background color to the outer element that holds all the elements that you want to have equal height.

http://jsfiddle.net/W7sYZ/4/

Comment: Not acceptable. The background color is applied to the hyperlink because it needs an active state when content is active.

Comment: I dont see where the problem is. You just apply different background color to the link separately.. just like you would normally. The reason why your active isn't showing is because in the css code it has `.tabbed` infront of it so it cant find the element you've assigned it to look for ( `.tabbed .module-controls .tab-set li.active a` *should be*  `.module-controls .tab-set li.active a`) only thing you gotta do then is to remove the extra space on top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

here i got the solution for equal height div using flex method.

```
<div class="card-row">
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
        <p>Sample content</p>      
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="button">button</a>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
        <p>Sample content</p>
        <p>Sample content two</p>
        <p>Sample content three</p>    
        <p>Sample content two</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="button">button</a>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
        <p>Sample content</p>
        <p>Sample content two</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="button">button</a>
</div>
```

//css

```
.card {
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0px 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.card-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 40px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
.card-content {
  background: #fff;
  flex: 1;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```