# Multicolumn subnavigation list floated left height adjustment?

Tags: css

I'm making a submenu that consists of an unordered list with its li elements floated left into two columns.

http://jsfiddle.net/orvn/mrCxu/

When a particular list item has more text than the others, it wraps and takes up more space than intended (which I'm okay with).

I can't seem to get the longer list items to fill the space of two of the other list items so there is no gap (see linked jsfiddle).

Suggestions? (I'm not terribly particular on the menu item order)

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">List item one</a></li>
        <li><a href="">List item two</a></li>    
        <li><a href="">List item three is longer</a></li> 
        <li><a href="">List item four</a></li>
        <li><a href="">List item five</a></li>
        <li><a href="">List item six</a></li>
        <li><a href="">List item seven</a></li>
        <li><a href="">List item eight</a></li>
        <li><a href="">List item nine</a></li>
        <li><a href="">List item ten</a></li>
        <li><a href="">List item eleven</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {width:140px; margin:10px 0 0 10px; padding:0} 
#wrapper ul {list-style-type: none; margin:0; padding:0}
#wrapper ul li {float:left;}
#wrapper ul li a {display:block; height:100%; width:64px; border:1px solid}
```

Comment: Sibling items do not know how big each other are. You need JavaScript to find the largest and set all the rest accordingly.

Comment: Can you think of any way at all to hack this to work in pure CSS? My JS is pretty weak.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567541/auto-adjust-height-make-equal-height-of-all-elements-using-css-css3